# Passing log or config reference to custom Go package

Tags: go, dependencies, package

I have a Go main-application that uses a custom `log` package and a custom `config` package.

This application "consumes" other packages that they need more logging or config parameters. Perhaps, a useful example is a custom `api-package`:

- It should print some `debug|info|warning` logs (the errors are managed as usual by the caller, in this case, the main-application).
- It should have access to values stored in the config (e.g. a server url/port, the environment of the main-application (development, test or production),... ).

I see three solutions to solve this problem:

1. Passing a pointer (of `log` and `config`) from the main object to the sub-package when the package is "initialised", then it will use this pointer like the main-application.
2. Initialise these dependencies (`log` or `config`) directly into the sub-package too, but this could raise concurrency issues between the main-application's instance vs. the package's instance.
3. Pass to each method the required arguments (but I would like to avoid build methods with huge args list).

At the moment I use method 1, am I doing it right?
What is the Go conventions about this?
Are there other ways to solve this?

---

EDIT

Just to explain, why it is not a duplicate of the proposed "duplicated" questions:

- The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538668/logging-globally-across-packages) proposed by icza: it takes care only for `logging` (writing "somewhere") and not for `config` (reading and writing). No other options are taken in consideration, for example which one follow at best the standards, which one is more performant,...
- The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361750/correct-approach-to-global-logging-in-golang) proposed by icza: it takes only care about a single application, this is not the case at all, because I already know how use the `logging` and the `config` in one "application" (or in goroutines).

If you mark as duplicate, please just explain why. So I can see if this is a really duplicate or if my question was misunderstand.

Comment: are you changing the config at runtime? i like solution 2 if it not change.

Comment: Also related: [Logging globally (across packages)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538668/logging-globally-across-packages)

Comment: @JiangYD yep, it can (rarely) change

Comment: @icza I don't think is really a duplicate of that answer. It is discussed only one way there (similar to my solution-proposal ```1.```), but it is not take in consideration any other option. Furthermore, the ```config``` topic is not discussed at all.

Comment: Do the custom `log` and `config` packages require parameters produced by the main app? Can't they just initialize themselves?

Comment: yep @icza it can be "custom" flags provided (for example) from the cli while starting-up (e.g.: the log could have the ```-debug=true|false```,  the config could have ```-config_location=somewhere```). Then I think that they can't initialize themselves (because they could miss the main-app flags).

Comment: A further issue, could be that the config can be updated - then in this case a package or the main-app could be not anymore in sync (have the same configs values) - ever in the case they initialise themselves. Using a reference solves this, but is the right way?