# Profiling/Logging Go Routines in GoLang

Tags: debugging, go, profiling

Using go's standard tooling, is there any way to -- log? profile? report on? -- the go routines a program invokes?

The specific use cases I'm thinking of are

1. Debugging concurrency issues/race conditions (i.e. which go routines ran when for a specific run of a program)
2. Identifying poorly performing go routines (how often is a particular go routine invoked, how long is go spending in an individual go routine)

Is there standard tooling for doing this sort of debugging?  If not, are there de-facto standard third party libraries for this sort of thing?  Or does go's culture encourage developers to build this sort of profiling into their own applications and systems?

Comment: Off the top of my head... add logging to the goroutines, using contexts https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/context-logging/, build your own logger interface https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361750/correct-approach-to-global-logging-in-golang, use a third party logging interface https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus.  Race conditions can be handled directly with go tooling https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html. Same with  poorly performing routines https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: Look at `pprof`. Very handy. Also build your code with the `-race` option to detect race conditions. You have to arrange for all goroutines to run though, it won't find races unless the code actually executes.

Comment: Read this: https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs especially go all the way to the end where the embedded profiler is explained. It can be built into a server app and accessed over HTTP.

Comment: And this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/05/10/debugging-performance-issues-in-go-programs especially scroll down to the section labelled "Blocking Profiler"

Comment: You might also be interested in the [go execution tracer](https://golang.org/cmd/trace/)